# boolean type for while loop in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line

I have a cron script on a shared web host that occasionally gets killed. I'd like to make a loop in bash that tries again if it gets killed, because most of the time it will make it. I'm having trouble with the syntax for storing a boolean value :P

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=0;

while [ $VAR ]; do
    if nice -19 mysqldump -uuser -ppassword -h database.hostname.com --skip-opt --all --complete-insert --add-drop-table database_name > ~/file/system/path/filename.sql; then
        VAR=1;
    fi
done
```

So the script recovers from a killed process okay, but once it's run properly, the new `VAR` value doesn't kill the `while` loop.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
while [ "$VAR" -eq 0 ]; do
```

`0` and `1` are both considered True because they are not null strings.

Comment: That's right, but for how I wrote it in my script, it should actually be `-ne 1` :)

Answer (score 8):

No need to you a helper variable, consider using:

```
while ! mysqldump .....; do :;done
```

Comment: What does the colon mean after do?

Comment: No operation: Just to satisfy bash syntax.

Answer (score 3):

In Bash, you can do a numeric conditional using double parentheses rather than a string conditional, but the logic is inverted:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=1;

while (( VAR )); do
    if nice -19 mysqldump -uuser -ppassword -h database.hostname.com --skip-opt --all --complete-insert --add-drop-table database_name > ~/file/system/path/filename.sql; then
        VAR=0;
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `/bin/true` and `/bin/false`. Although `while ! mysqldump .....; do :;done` (Jürgen Hötzel's solution) would be better in this case, there are other cases when using `true` and `false` are useful.

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=true

while $VAR; do
  if nice -19 mysqldump -uuser -ppassword -h database.hostname.com --skip-opt --all --complete-insert --add-drop-table database_name > ~/file/system/path/filename.sql; then
    VAR=false
  fi
done
```

Comment: I was going to say "mmmm. Shouldn't it be VAR=`true` AND var=`false` ?
Because - unless error - VAR=true means assigning the string 'true' to VAR. and VAR=false means assigning 'false' to VAR."... but No, because while $VAR executes $VAR.

Answer (score 1):

I like `until` better for this... :

```
i=0
until [ $_done ]; do
   echo stuff...;
   sleep 1;
   (( i++ ));
   if [ "$i" -gt 9 ]; then
      _done=1
   fi
done
```