# Pass condition into a function

Tags: bash, shell

I´m trying to pass to a function a condition to be applied in a while loop, and if it´s true increase a variable of that condition.
If that´s possible on bash?. Here an example code

```
a(){
    condition=$1
    echo "condition:$condition"
    while [[ $condition ]] # --> run the condition
    do
        num1=num1+1
        echo "increase num1:$num1"  # num1 is a var of the condition
    done   
}


b(){
    num1=1
    num2=3
    `a $num1 < $num2` 
}

b
```

Comment: Probably this is answering your question: [boolean type for while loop in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693732/1983854)

Comment: You can't do `num1=num1+1` by the way. Did you mean `(( num1++ ))`?

Comment: I don't think you can pass a command to be later on evaluated (unless you perform an `eval` within `while`, which would be quite ugly), so -to me- the usage of some condition that is either 0 or not and the answer above would be the best way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use as below;

```
#! /bin/bash

a(){
    condition="(( \$num $2 $3 ))"
    num=$1
    while eval $condition
      do
        (( num++ ))
        echo "increase num1:$num" 
      done   
}


b(){
    num1=1
    num2=5
    a $num1 '<' $num2
}

b
```

Comment: This solution assumes that always the expression will have 3 items and that first one will be always the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `eval`, I would just pass the name of a function which `a` can call.

```
a () {
    while "$1"; do
        ...
    done
}

b(){
    num1=1
    num2=3
    c () (( num1 < num2 ))
    a c
}

b
```

(Keep in mind that functions are always global; `c` is not local to the body of `b`.)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like below :

```
a(){
    num1="$1";
    num2="$3";
    if [ "$2" = "<" ]
    then
    op="-lt"
    elif [ "$2" = ">" ]
    then
    op="-gt"
    else
    op="-eq"
    fi
    condition="$num1 $op $num2"
    while eval "[ $condition ]" # --> evaluate the condition
    do
        ((num1++)) #num1=num1+1 is in the original is wrong.
        echo "increased num1:$num1"  
        condition="$num1 $op $num2" #rebuild the condition
    done
}

b(){
    num1=1
    num2=3
    a "$num1" '<' "$num2" #quote the params, else '<' stands for redirection
}

b
```

Comment: Try it with: a "$num1" '<=' "$num2"

Comment: @pasabaporaqui : Of course, the op is suppose to add more test cases as required ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
#!/bin/bash 

a(){
    condition="expr $1 > /dev/null"
    while eval $condition; do
        echo "num1=$num1 num2=$num2"  
        let num1++
    done   
}


b(){
    num1=1
    num2=3
    a '$num1 \< $num2'
}

b
```

remember the command `expr 1 < 3` produces an error:

```
$ expr 1 < 3
bash: 3: No such file or directory
```

this is the reason to write `\<` instead of `<`

Comment: This is  indeed a smarter way to do it.. :) At the same time doesn't guarantee that the while loop would terminate say had the condition been `$num + 3` .